# Check if OS Printer Correctly Printed Jasper Report

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I print a jasper report on a default printer of operacional system. But I need to check if the report was correctly printed (not canceled and without errors).

To print report I use this code:

```
private void printOnPrinter(JasperPrint jasperPrint, String printer) throws JRException {

    PrintServiceAttributeSet psas = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
    psas.add(new PrinterName(printer, null));

    JRPrintServiceExporter jrpse = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
    jrpse.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    jrpse.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, psas);
    jrpse.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    jrpse.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);

    try {
        jrpse.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I tried to use this code to check but always return success:

```
    Boolean[] printStatus = jrpse.getPrintStatus();
    for (Boolean status : printStatus) {
        if (!status) {
            System.err.println("Not correctly printed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is highly unlikely you can get device specific information from the printer without access to the device driver and spooling system.  By "doesn't work" I assume you mean it always returns success, which just means the print job was correctly passed to the spooling system. As far as the Java code can determine the job "printed" correctly.  What happens after the job is spooled is not visible to your code.

Comment: Exactly. Probably a new thread was created and passed to the operating system and may be beyond the control of JVM. So I posted here to see if exite something I can do in this case.

Comment: No, the spooling system and printer driver are completely outside the JVM. They are part of the operating system.